# PHP Validation Trouble

Tags: php, validation

I'm working on a final project for a PHP class and I'm having trouble with validating the code. In the else if part of the code I always get an error at both of these else if statements and the application stops processing. 
The code below is a part of a .php file that has a HTML form for setting reminders.

```
} else if (!checkdate($_POST['reminderMonth'],$_POST['reminderDate'],$_POST['remindereEar'])) {
    $error_message = "Selected date does not exist.";
} else if ($reminderDate <= $t_date) {
    $error_message = "Selected date has already occured.";
```

All of the code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
//get data
$t_date = date(Ymd);
$year = $_POST['reminderYear'];
$month = $_POST['reminderMonth'];
$day = $_POST['reminderDay'];
//validate data
$reminderDate = $year.$month.$day;
if (empty($_POST['reminderName'])) {
    $error_message = "Name is a required field.";
} else if (!checkdate($_POST['reminderMonth'],$_POST['reminderDate'],$_POST['remindereEar'])) {
    $error_message = "Selected date does not exist.";
} else if ($reminderDate <= $t_date) {
    $error_message = "Selected date has already occured.";
} else {
    $error_message = ''; }
//redirect
if(empty($error_message)) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO reminder_event 
                    (reminderName,reminderDescript,reminderDate) 
                 VALUES
                    ('{$reminderName}','{$reminderDescript}','{$reminderDate}')");
header("Refresh: 1;url=reminder_list.php");
} else {
echo($error_message); } }
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed that...tired from all of the cramming for exams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

date(Ymd) will produce error should be

```
date('Y m d');
```

and make sure $reminderDate = $year.$month.$day; is formatted in the same way

```
$reminderDate = $year.' '.$month.' '.$day;
```

Also 2 typos:

```
$_POST['reminderDate'],$_POST['remindereEar']
```

Dont know if this is a solution, but still looks like it will cause problems if you run it your way

Comment: It seems that the year and month are stored in the database, but the actual date isn't.

Comment: what is the date col set to in sql date or datetime? it needs to be date for that format

Comment: may need to add format like this: date('y-m-d') and same for $reminderDate = $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day; also make sure all recheck for any typos, and make sure dont get mixed up with $_POST['reminderDate'] and $_POST['reminderDay'] anwhere else in the script, make sure $_POST['reminderYear'] is also the same throughout the script

Comment: if none of these work, either send me the full script (not sure im allowed to give email on here though) or repost full code and i will run it on my server and try to work it out for you

Comment: I changed the size of the field in the database and now it's working. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 typos:

```
 $_POST['reminderDate'],$_POST['remindereEar']
```

It should be:

```
$_POST['reminderDay'],$_POST['reminderYear']
```

Comment: Just fixed it, still getting errors. Now it's with the 2nd else if statement, first statement appears to work.

Comment: See @Wesley's answer below to fix that

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake with reminderDate and remindereEar.

It should be instead : `$_POST['reminderDay'], $_POST['reminderYear']`

Tell me if you get more error after changing that.

Comment: Just fixed it, still getting errors. Now it's with the 2nd else if statement, first statement appears to work.

Comment: Try this : $reminderDate = $year.' '.$month.' '.$day; and you can also try to change that : date('Y m d'); if it is not working.